# Get the substring from a string if the string contains the substring in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, search, substring

We can do this using programming languages. But getting the result from mysql is hard to find.

I have column in a table that has string values.

> ex: saturday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday sunday

If I search `monday` from the above string, the query should give only `monday` as my result.

I need to get only the searched word from the string as a mysql result.

I tried the following query.

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(usertext,'STORY',0) FROM `usertext`
```

But it didn't give any result.

I am looking for regular expression to find the solution.

If my question is not clear, kindly comment.

Comment: Should it only match complete words? If you were to search for "day" should it return anything then? And are all words unique or can there be two mondays in a string? What happens if you search for monday then?

Comment: It should match complete word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
select SUBSTR(usertext, INSTR(usertext, 'sunday'), length('sunday'))  
from myTable 
where CONCAT(' ', usertext, ' ') rlike ' sunday ';
```

If you are sure that you always search for complete words then a simpler version can be:

```
select SUBSTR(usertext, INSTR(usertext, 'sunday'), length('sunday'))
from myTable
where usertext like '%sunday%';
```

As far as i know MySql dont have support for regular expression in the select to get out values, only for the where part.

Comment: Thanks bro. Excellent